# Bulk postgres insert where timestamp has null constraint set through sequalize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Postgres and Sequelize with my node app.

I have set up the models and allows Sequalize to produce the tables. I now want to move the data across using something like this.
`insert into archive (id,title) select id, title from old_archives;`
However, I am getting null errors as Sequelize uses createdAt and updatedAt columns. Is there a way around this?

Error is

> ERROR:  null value in column "createdAt" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, null, Dewerstone Rocks, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).

Comment: Update: I have cheated for now and added dummy dates in the old table so I can copy them across. Perhaps not the answer though...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of altering the old table you could alter the select statement to generate the required date

```
INSERT INTO archive (id, title, createdAt) SELECT id, title, NOW() FROM old_archives;
```

This selects the data from the old table, plus adds the current timestamp to each row. Of course you could also insert any other date you want instead of `NOW()`